# How to eliminate NULL columns from ResultSet

Tags: sql-server

```html
DECLARE @Doc INT ='20'
SELECT DISTINCT 

       [Name or title]
      ,[Subject]
      ,[Approval Description]
      ,[TypeOfApproval]
      ,[TypeOfExpense]
      ,[ExpenseNature]
      ,[BudgetType]
      ,[Current State]
      ,CASE
      WHEN [Current State] = 'Initiator' 
      THEN [IniSignature] 
    END AS RES
    
     ,CASE
      WHEN [Current State] = 'Initiator' 
      THEN [IniSignatureName]
     
   END AS RES1
    
   ,CASE
      WHEN [Current State] = 'Reviewer' 
      THEN [ReviewerSignatureName]
   END AS RES2

,CASE
      WHEN [Current State] = 'Reviewer' 
      THEN [ReviewerSignature] 
   END AS RES3


 ,CASE 
  WHEN [Current State]  = 'Reviewer' 
  THEN [IniSignatureName]
 
   END AS RES4
 
 ,CASE
      WHEN [Current State] = 'Reviewer' 
      THEN [IniSignature]
   END AS RES5
 
 ,CASE 
  WHEN [Current State]  = 'Approved' 
  THEN [ApprovedSignatureName] 
  
END AS RES6

,CASE 
  WHEN [Current State]  = 'Approved' 
  THEN [ApprovedSignature] 
  
END AS RES7

,CASE 
  WHEN [Current State]  = 'Approved' 
  THEN [ReviewerSignatureName]
  
END AS RES8

,CASE 
  WHEN [Current State]  = 'Approved' 
  THEN [ReviewerSignature]
  
END AS RES9

,CASE 
  WHEN [Current State]  = 'Approved' 
  THEN [IniSignatureName]
  
END AS RES10

,CASE 
  WHEN [Current State]  = 'Approved' 
  THEN [IniSignature]
  
END AS RES11

FROM 
(

SELECT DISTINCT 

       [Name or title]
      ,[Subject]
      ,[Approval Description]
      ,TypeOfApproval.[Name] AS [TypeOfApproval]
      ,TypeOfExpense.[Name] AS [TypeOfExpense]
      ,ExpenseNature.[Name] AS [ExpenseNature]
      ,BudgetType.[Name] AS [BudgetType]
      ,UblState.Name AS [Current State] 
      ,IniSignature.[ImageBits] AS IniSignature
      ,IniSignatureName.CreatorName AS IniSignatureName
      ,ReviewerSignature.ImageBits AS ReviewerSignature
      ,ReviewerSignatureName.CreatorName AS ReviewerSignatureName
      ,ApprovedSignature.ImageBits AS ApprovedSignature
      ,ApprovedSignatureName.CreatorName AS ApprovedSignatureName  
 
  FROM [SaveImage].[dbo].[UBL] Rec
  
  LEFT JOIN  [SaveImage].[dbo].[UBL_State_Changes] ON [SaveImage].[dbo].[UBL_State_Changes].[State_ID] = Rec.[State_ID]
  
  LEFT JOIN [SaveImage].[dbo].[UBL_ApprovalType] ON [SaveImage].[dbo].[UBL_ApprovalType].[UBL_ID] = Rec.[ID]
  
  LEFT JOIN [SaveImage].[dbo].[ApprovalType] TypeOfApproval ON TypeOfApproval.[ID] =  [SaveImage].[dbo].[UBL_ApprovalType].[ApprovalType_ID]
 
  LEFT JOIN [SaveImage].[dbo].[UBL_Nature of Expense] ON [SaveImage].[dbo].[UBL_Nature of Expense].[UBL_ID] = Rec.[ID]
 
  LEFT JOIN [SaveImage].[dbo].[Expense] TypeOfExpense ON TypeOfExpense.[ID] = [SaveImage].[dbo].[UBL_Nature of Expense].[Nature of Expense_ID]
  
  LEFT JOIN [SaveImage].[dbo].[UBL_Nature of Expense] NatureOfExpense ON [SaveImage].[dbo].[UBL_Nature of Expense].[UBL_ID] = Rec.[ID]
  
  LEFT JOIN [SaveImage].[dbo].[Nature of Expense] ExpenseNature ON ExpenseNature.[ID] = [SaveImage].[dbo].[UBL_Nature of Expense].[Nature of Expense_ID]
  
  LEFT JOIN [SaveImage].[dbo].[UBL_Budget Status] ON [SaveImage].[dbo].[UBL_Budget Status].[UBL_ID] = Rec.[ID]
  
  LEFT JOIN [SaveImage].[dbo].[Budget Status] BudgetType ON BudgetType.ID = [SaveImage].[dbo].[UBL_Budget Status].[Budget Status_ID]
    
  INNER JOIN [SaveImage].[dbo].[State] AS UblState ON Rec.[State_ID] = UblState.[ID]
  
  LEFT JOIN  [SaveImage].[dbo].[Img] AS Imj  ON Imj.[CreatorName] = UblState.Name
  
  LEFT JOIN  [SaveImage].[dbo].[Img] AS IniSignature ON IniSignature.CreatorName ='Initiator'
  
  LEFT JOIN  [SaveImage].[dbo].[Img] AS IniSignatureName ON [IniSignatureName].CreatorName ='Initiator'
  
  LEFT JOIN  [SaveImage].[dbo].[Img] AS ReviewerSignature ON ReviewerSignature.CreatorName ='Reviewer'
  
  LEFT JOIN  [SaveImage].[dbo].[Img] AS ReviewerSignatureName ON [ReviewerSignatureName].CreatorName ='Reviewer'
  
  LEFT JOIN  [SaveImage].[dbo].[Img] AS ApprovedSignature ON ApprovedSignature.CreatorName ='Approved'
  
  LEFT JOIN  [SaveImage].[dbo].[Img] AS ApprovedSignatureName   ON [ApprovedSignatureName].CreatorName ='Approved'
  
  
  WHERE  Rec.[ID] = (@Doc) 
  
  ) AS BaseTbl
```

I using T-SQL query in which defined multiple JOINS and the Result i am getting is exactly what my requirement is, Its like an object is moving through a workflow with different states and i am getting the Object status and relevant filed. For the required ResultSet i used CASE statement but i do not know why it is displaying the columns which have NULL. And i want to eliminate the NULL columns from my final Result set.The screen short of the Result-set is attached below.Any help would be great full.

**Result Set**
[image: ResultSet]

Thanks & Regards
Muhammad Sami ur Rehman

Comment: what do you mean by eliminate? Remove the column if null or just change the value if null?

Comment: I think OP wants to remove those columns whose values are `NULL`

Comment: It would be hard to tell at least (for me) without your actual query what it says.

Comment: Yes exactly i want to remove those columns whose values are NULL

Comment: What if your query gives another row with `RES4` column as NULL ? How'd you handle it, when 1 row has value for column whereas other row has NULL ?

Comment: Maybe you should solve this first `For the required ResultSet i used CASE statement but i do not know why it is displaying the columns which have NULL`

Comment: @YogeshSharma sir i can upload my query even if it would help me in getting the result without nulls

Comment: @Squirrel Sir, can you please describe it more .

Comment: @YogeshSharma you can find the Code now, i have uploaded it just now

Comment: @PrabhatG yes it will work for me though, i want to show the data in Report Builder

Comment: @MSamiUrRehman.. The query behavior works well as you define, just look at the `case` expression.

Comment: @YogeshSharma is it something wrong with the CASE Expression

Comment: Personally, I would handle the hiding of the columns in your presentation layer, not your SQL. If you're using SSRS, for example, visibility can easily be controlled with an expression. In SQL, you'll have to make your entire query dynamic; and it just makes things harder to support for a query that should be simple.

Comment: Larnu Sir, you was right i have managed to get the desired result set from your suggestion. Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

I can think of implementing this logic in stored procedure , not through one single query.

Declare a temporary table and insert full result from you query with multiple joins into the temporary table i.e. temporary table  should have same number of columns and type as returned by your query or you can use

```
SELECT * INTO #tempTable FROM ( <Your Query> )
```

Then use dyanmic sql to gnerate final column list based on series of IF conditions

```
DECLARE @colList VARCHAR(1000) = ''

-- If All values in col1 are NULL then COUNT(col1) gives zero    
IF (SELECT COUNT(col1) FROM #tempTable) > 0
   SET @colList = 'col1,'

IF (SELECT COUNT(col2) FROM #tempTable) > 0
   SET @colList = @colList + 'col2,'
.
.
.

IF (SELECT COUNT(colN) FROM #tempTable) > 0
   SET @colList = @colList + 'colN,'

IF @colList<>''
BEGIN
  --Remove last comma from column list
  SELECT @colList = LEFT(@colList,LEN(@colList) -1 )

  --EXEC SELECT query on generated colum list excluding columns which have ALL NULL values
  EXEC('SELECT ' + @colList + ' FROM #tempTable')

END
```